# How to enable certificate trust with Capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have following code:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, profile: "selenium")
  driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(600,800)
  driver
end
```

And during running test there is popup window with certificate so every time I have to press it.

How to automatically do it, or to configure Capybara firefox profile to automatically accept certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Firefox/Profile.html#assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer=-instance_method), you need to set `assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer` to `false` on your `Firefox::Profile`. Eg:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false # <= this should work
  driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :profile => profile)
  driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(600,800)
  driver
end
```

If you want to know the details of how this works in the firefox driver, see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/UntrustedSSLCertificates

Comment: I am using this code in pure Ruby. So just to add, selenium-webdriver should be included for this to work.